# How to find web element if it is changing in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

How do I create a Xpath of any element in web page when it is changes each page load or refresh using selenium

Comment: show examples of how it's changes

Comment: suppose if there is submit button ,it is changing its ID,name, css and Xpath also how do we find that

Comment: There is only 1 submit? What do it have special? Can you show sample

Comment: suppose there is a table of students end each time its adding new student lets say first time it displays 5 student information second time it displays 8 students (name ,branch, roll no) when user clicks on student no 6 it displays the information of that student. But my question it is changing everytime the element ID,Name an all thing how do we find that ??  dear @user7294900  user answer is correct only when the table is static but in my case the table is dynamically changing

Answer (score 0):

If there is 1 submit button, you can find element by checking input type submit

```
 //input[@type='submit']
```

If there are more and you know it place in page for example 2. Search by child number as:

```
( //input[@type='submit']) [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method it works fine.
Here is my **xpath**,

`//*[@id="CaseTypes_39aa6635-cd44-4104-a9f7-e33c3f96e2ab__Amount"]`

Here is my code:

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[starts-with(@id, 'CaseTypes_') and substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('__Amount') +1) = '__Amount']")]
```

I hope it helps!!